# Add class-element to a link though a module (or can I implement theme_link in a module instead of in a theme)?

Tags: 7, theming

I'm the developer and maintainer of a module on the Drupal website. It implements an API so that a certain third party service can be easily integrated in Drupal.

I'm currently having the following problem: I need to add a class-element to the logout link. So my module has to arrange that all the these links `<a href="/user/logout">Log out</a>` becomes the following: `<a href="/user/logout" class="mymodule">Log out</a>`

For the logout link in a menu it's easy, I have to implement `hook_menu_link_alter()`.

However, I also want to catch all occurences where somebody is using `l("Log out", "/user/logout")`. The latter function calls `theme_link`, so if I would implement that, I think it could solve my problem.

So my questions are:

1. Can I implement theme_link in a module? If so, can somebody tell me how to do this?
2. Is there another way in which the above could be accomplished by means of a module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OSSGuys pointed me in the good direction. I needed to implement hook_preprocess_hook, in my case I needed hook_preprocess_link:

The code that finally solved my problem is:

```
function mymodule_preprocess_link(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['path'] == 'user/logout') {
    $variables['options']['attributes']['class'][] = 'mymodule';
  }
}
```

Comment: Important note: this doesn't work on Drupal 6! I guess because `theme('link', ...)` is not called from the `l()` function.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you want to have a class in every link that comes on the site.
I believe, you can achieve this by skinr module - https://drupal.org/project/skinr, which not only adds up classes but also provides you UI to achieve the same.

Also, in module, you can try this.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_HOOK
 */
function MODULENAME_preprocess_menu_link (&$variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#original_link']['menu_name'] == 'main-menu') {
    $variables['element']['#title'] = '<i class="icon-' . _sanitize_words($variables['element']['#title']) . '"></i>' . $variables['element']['#title'];
  }
}
```

The above could should work, Worked for me atleast :)

Comment: Thanks for the hint on hook_preprocess_hook! However, your implementation will only change links in menus, I wanted to change ALL links. So it turns out that I needed hook_preprocess_link !!